# SSD and Lenovo X60s laptop dont get along under Windows and Linux

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ssd, hardware-failure

I put an SSD in my Lenovo X60s laptop and the two do not seem to get along. I tried to install Windows 7 and 8 several times and I got several different errors, most often:

> windows setup could not configure windows to run on this computer's hardware

After restart:

> Disk Read Failure press ctrl alt del

Also:

> Page fault in nonpaged area

And:

> We couldn't install Windows on the Location you chose. Here's more info about what happened: 0x80300024

Also sometimes I cannot create a partition in Windows installer.

Things I tried so far:

- Checking if my BIOS is the latest version.
- Trying to load drivers for an [Intel Raid controller](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2466753). It didn't recognize them.
- Switching to AHCI (this was the default). I also tried the other option, which is "Compatibility".
- Removing the SSD after the installation to check what happend (the partitions were created but I could not open them).
- Formatting the SSD in another computer and then trying to install Windows on an already formatted drive.

I also changed the RAM at the same time.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

**Update:** I also tried Ubuntu. It installed without errors but the first time I tried to shut it down it stuck on the Ubuntu logo. After a manual restart it gave me an error:

> error: unknown filesystem

Comment: I have an X61 with an (aftermarket) Intel SSD and it works without complaint. Are you sure your SSD isn't faulty? Stick the SSD into another laptop/desktop and see if you can install an OS on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incompatibility between the laptop's chipset and the SSD.

Fixed by firmware update:
http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?95716-Vertex-Plus-firmware-3-55 (you will have to do it from a different PC)